# CS0123 - No overload for 'TextChanged' matches delegate 'EventHandler'

Tags: c#, winforms

Full disclosure yes this is homework and yes I've tried researching my issues but still am not getting how to fix it.

So I'm trying to only allow numbers to be entered into a textbox. I did so using KeyPressEventArgs parameter.

```
private void classAinput_TextChanged(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
        e.Handled = true;
    else
    {
        invalidFormatError();

    }
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

That worked well enough for me but I get an CS0123 error saying:

> No overload for 'classAinput_TextChanged' matches delegate
>   'EventHandler'

inside of the designer code.

Why is this?

```
// 
// classAinput
// 
this.classAinput.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(67, 51);
this.classAinput.Name = "classAinput";
this.classAinput.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
this.classAinput.TabIndex = 4;
this.classAinput.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.classAinput_TextChanged);
//
```

Full Form 1 Code: https://hastebin.com/husececuri.cs

Comment: [`TextChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event handler needs `(Object sender, EventArgs e)` parameters.

Comment: If for any reason you need to handle [`KeyPress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx) you should attach the event handler having `(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)` parameters to `KeyPress` event.

Comment: @RezaAghaei How do I attatch the event handler to the KeyPress event?

Comment: Take a look at this line of code: `this.classAinput.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.classAinput_TextChanged);` It's generated by designer. If you go to designer and select `classAinput` text box, in the properties window, in events, you can see `classAinput_TextChanged` method is assigned to `TextChanged`. cut that name and paste it in front of `KeyPress` event.

Comment: Once you have your handlers fixed... setting `e.Handled=true` the second time seems wrong. It would mark every key handled unless `invalidFormatError` throws an exception (in which case *that* would be wrong). Also, what if I wanted to hit backspace? I wouldn't be able to.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are currently supplying `TextChanged` with an incorrect method. The `TextChanged` Event requries `object` and `EventArgs` types as parameters. Since your goal is catching the key press event, delete your current method, add this to your form:

```
 private void classAinput_KeyPressed(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
 {
    if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
        e.Handled = true;
    else
    {
        invalidFormatError();

    }
    e.Handled = true;
 }
```

And on your designer, it would be:

```
this.classAinput.KeyPressed += new System.EventHandler(this.classAinput_KeyPressed);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `TextChanged` event doesn't accept a `KeyPressEventArgs`. [`KeyPress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx) does, so subscribe to that instead:

```
this.classAinput.KeyPress += new System.KeyPressEventHandler(this.classAinput_TextChanged);
```

Alternatively, you can try `int.TryParse` with the `TextChanged` event. The implementation could go something like this:

```
private void classAinput_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!(classAinput.Text == "" || int.TryParse(classAinput.Text, out int _))) {
        invalidFormatError();
    }
}
```